# Undefined index: message in PHP contact form

Tags: php, undefined-index

I have a simple contact form on a website that was moved to new server, and now they are receiving blank entries every day.

Here is the form code:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "info@mywebsite.com";
$EmailTo = "guyf@mywebsite.com";
$Subject = "Website Contact";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Company = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Company'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "The following is a contact us form submitted from your website.";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "NAME:  ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "COMPANY:  ";
$Body .= $Company;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "EMAIL:  ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "MESSAGE:  ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"     content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

And here are the PHP errors that I'm getting, which don't make sense to me since I entered information on those lines. Could it be the blank entry?

```
[04-Dec-2015 11:41:09 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Name in /home6/mywebsite/public_html/contact-f-2/contactengine.php on line 6
[04-Dec-2015 11:41:09 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Company in /home6/mywebsite/public_html/contact-f-2/contactengine.php on line 7
[04-Dec-2015 11:41:09 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Email in /home6/mywebsite/public_html/contact-f-2/contactengine.php on line 8
[04-Dec-2015 11:41:09 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Message in /home6/mywebsite/public_html/contact-f-2/contactengine.php on line 9
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Check your form `method` is post and the relevant input elements `name` match your `$_POST` key

Comment: How does your form look like (HTML)?

Comment: Please add the HTML code for your form.